# application like the watch window of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

i'm planning to create an application like the watch window of visual studio but i have no idea of how and where to start to create something like this or what are the things that must be learned. I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

You could learn C#, WPF, WinForm or even UWP, please visit MSDN you will find the official tutorial of them. i.e here is the [get started with WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/getting-started-with-wpf).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but I don't think you understand my question.. you also remove the debugging tag.. have you tried the watch window debugger in visual studio?

Comment: Based on your original post, you want to develop a extension work integrated with Visual Studio like Watch window or a standalone application?  Either of them seems related to developing a application other than about debugging some app with using the debugging tools in VS, isn't it?